# Open react native expo app external links outside the app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using the following code. Apple is not pleased that all external links are opening within app. How should I modify my code below so that external links open in outisde app safari instead of within app safari.

My `App.js` is as following:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import {ActivityIndicator, Platform,  TouchableOpacity, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
const App = () => {
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false)
  const [canGoForward, setCanGoForward] = useState(false)
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('')
  const webviewRef = useRef(null)
  backButtonHandler = () => {
    if (webviewRef.current) webviewRef.current.goBack()
  }
  
  frontButtonHandler = () => {
    if (webviewRef.current) webviewRef.current.goForward()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' />
      <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
        <WebView 
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Mobile Safari/537.36"
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=restaurants+nearby&ct=ifl&cad=2:hungry&ei=IWHsX_aDGJK0swXew5HgBw&ved=0ahUKEwi2mN_oyfXtAhUS2qwKHd5hBHwQnRsIDg&rct=j' }}
        mixedContentMode = "compatibility"
          ref={webviewRef}
          onNavigationStateChange={navState => {
            setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack)
            setCanGoForward(navState.canGoForward)
            setCurrentUrl(navState.url)
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.tabBarContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={backButtonHandler}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={32} color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={frontButtonHandler}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-forward" size={32} color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop:Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
  tabBarContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
  },
  button: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20
  }
})

export default App
```

Edit: Can you please provide a modified version of `App.js` above as I have already read through the various help documentation and codes there.

Comment: Can you use https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking?

Comment: did you check my answer

Comment: Yes I did. Please look at my question. My problem was that I wasn't able to translate the expo code to my vesion of App.js file. I was already aware of expo documentation and sample codes.

Answer (score 2):

## Expo

you can use [expo-web-browser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) because Apple wants is to have it clearly visible that it is an external URL.

### Installation

```
expo install expo-web-browser
```

`expo-web-browser` provides access to the system's web browser and supports handling redirects. On iOS, it uses `SFSafariViewController` or `SFAuthenticationSession`, depending on the method you call, and on Android it uses `ChromeCustomTabs`. As of iOS 11, `SFSafariViewController` no longer shares cookies with Safari, so if you are using `WebBrowser` for authentication you will want to use `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync`, and if you just want to open a webpage (such as your app privacy policy), then use `WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync`

### Usage

https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/basic-webbrowser-usage

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.io');
    setResult(result);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={_handlePressButtonAsync} />
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

## React Native

you can use the following library [react-native-inappbrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser)

follow the installation from the github page

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
import InAppBrowser from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'

...
  async openLink() {
    try {
      const url = 'https://www.google.com'
      if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
        const result = await InAppBrowser.open(url, {
          // iOS Properties
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          readerMode: false,
          animated: true,
          modalPresentationStyle: 'overFullScreen',
          modalTransitionStyle: 'partialCurl',
          modalEnabled: true,
          // Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
          toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
          secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
          // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
          // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
          animations: {
            startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
            startExit: 'slide_out_left',
            endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
            endExit: 'slide_out_right'
          },
          headers: {
            'my-custom-header': 'my custom header value'
          },
          waitForRedirectDelay: 0
        })
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(result))
      }
      else Linking.openURL(url)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
    }
  }
...
```

you can check [the example app here](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/tree/master/example)

for expo it becomes little bit complicated please check the related [tutorial by Medium](https://medium.com/lazy-engineering/creating-an-embedded-browser-with-react-native-aea42b54740)

if you want reading mode in ios please refer this link

[reader-mode-webview-component-for-react-native](https://reactnativeexample.com/cross-platform-safari-like-reader-mode-webview-component-for-react-native/)

Answer (score 1):

You've embedded a webview. What Apple wants, is to have it clearly visible that it is an external URL.

There is what's called Safari UI View Controller on IOS, and Chrome Custom tabs on Android.

There are a couple of plugins out there, but I liked using this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

Comment: Thanks, but I am new to this so I am not sure what my new App.js will look like ??